# Data validation to search for certain text and input message

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dropdown menu in cell A1 with different mode options (ex mode A, mode B, mode C) and next to this theres another drop down in cell A2 where the user can enter the level they want (ex. level 1, level 2, level 3). Then, theres a cell (B2) where they enter a number between 1 and 3. I would like a pop-up message to appear when the user clicks on B2 and the options are set to mode C and level 2 or 3. So far I have been using this in the data validation box but the input message appears all the time, even if the specified modes/levels arent there. The data validation is in cell B2

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("mode C", A1)), OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("Level 2", A3)),ISNUMBER(FIND("Level 3", A2)))
```

Comment: Data Validation "Input Message" is intended for user input guidance, similar to the gray text that only appears when a text field is empty. It will not function in the way you desire. You should use either an "Error Alert" and redefine your validation formula or, if you want to enact some action/update values, create a button in B2 that will give you an error/warning pop-up message if A1 and A2 settings are incorrect.

Comment: @pmackni how should I redefine the validation formula?

Answer (score 0):

Joey,

I got some workaround to solve your issue. see below -

i defined the formula in one cell(for custom validation purpose) that will give me output as TRUE & FALSE

=IF(AND(A1="Mode C",OR(A3="Level 2",A3="Level 3")),TRUE,FALSE)

Let assume i have this formula in Cell B1.

Now My Custom Validation formula will become like below for Cell B2 -

=$B$1=FALSE

Thats All.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you share some example on the level of versions

Comment: I actually figured that part out, the first equation works with the FIND function, however I still cannot get a pop up to appear. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: if you are getting the TRUE / FALSE value through formula then there should not be any proble, now you just have to put the custom validation on cell you entering the value. try checking both - =$B$1=FALSE  if it is not working test with =$B$1=TRUE ( saying this as i dont know how you written first formula)

Comment: Ive tried those, and there's nothing that appears. I also have a cell that sums the TRUE/FALSE cells to see if at least one is true: =IF( OR(C2="TRUE", C3="TRUE", C4="TRUE"), TRUE, FALSE) And this only outputs false when it should be true. Is it wrong

Comment: I fixed it and everything works, except the pop up message appears only the first time and does not appear again when the TRUE/FALSE condition changes